# Getting document type that is knitted in knitr

Tags: r, knitr

I'm using [code externalization](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/externalization/) in `knitr`. I have an `myRcode.R` file that includes codes and I have two kinds of reports I want to produce. One latex file (`myLatexFile.RNW`) and one html file (`myHtmlFile.RMD`). Both are calling chunks from the `myRcode.R` file. I want to get different outputs depending on the extension that calls the chunk.

Right now, my solution is this something like this:

```
library(stringr)
if (str_sub(current_input(),-3,-1) == "Rmd") {
  cat("HTML file...")
} else if (str_sub(current_input(),-3,-1) == "Rnw") 
  cat("LATEX file...")
```

But there should be a native function that gets the file type within the knitr. I couldn't find it. Is there such function in knitr?

Comment: See this as I think it will be of use: https://trinkerrstuff.wordpress.com/2014/11/18/rmarkdown-alter-action-depending-on-document/

Comment: In theory `knitr::opts_knit$get("rmarkdown.pandoc.to")` is what I want. But it returns `NULL` when I knit a latex document. For html files it works though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In \`knitr\` how can I test for if the output will be PDF or word?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35144130/in-knitr-how-can-i-test-for-if-the-output-will-be-pdf-or-word)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out [in an answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48458182/), `knitr` 1.18 [introduced](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/NEWS.md#changes-in-knitr-version-118) the following functions

```
knitr::is_html_output()
knitr::is_latex_output()
```

which check at compile-time if the output is HTML or LaTeX, and return TRUE/FALSE. Something like the following would work:

```
if (knitr::is_html_output()) {
  cat("HTML file...")
} else if (knitr::is_latex_output()) { 
  cat("LATEX file...")
}
```