# Can you access the output format of R Markdown at render time?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I understand how to explicitly create and use parameters in R Markdown. I have a report with multiple output formats. At render time, I would like to know which output format is current target. Output format does not show up in `params`, but, following the DRY principle, I'd like to avoid adding an second, explicit parameter for this. Does anyone know a way to access output format at render time?

Comment: How is the output format actually selected? The `output_format` option of `rmarkdown::render`, or are you using knitr? `rmarkdown::all_output_formats` would normally work, but I'm not sure it would here.

Comment: You should be able to dynamically determine the target output with `knitr::opts_knit$get("rmarkdown.pandoc.to")`. (Assuming I have understood your question )

Comment: This may be relevant? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35144130/in-knitr-how-can-i-test-for-if-the-output-will-be-pdf-or-word/35149103

Comment: The question (and accepted answer) you link to @Benjamin is spot on. So this should probably be marked as duplicate and linked to that.

Comment: @jennybryan I blogged about this a while back: https://trinkerrstuff.wordpress.com/2014/11/18/rmarkdown-alter-action-depending-on-document/

Comment: Thanks @TylerRinker. Nice!