# How to do different things in R in bookdown if output is html or latex

Tags: r, bookdown

I am using bookdown to generate html and pdf at the same time. I would like to use dynamic tables (DT) in the html version, but a normal table in the pdf file. Is there a way to do this in markdown without having to have to separate files as input and using the yml file.
Something like

```
if (output = html) {
    DT...
}
if (output = "pdf"){
    xlatex ...
}
```

THanks
Renger

Comment: It looks like you can use the same approach described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35144130/in-knitr-how-can-i-test-for-if-the-output-will-be-pdf-or-word/35149103.  I had marked this as a duplicate, then retracted it because I wasn't sure if the `bookdown` mechanism was the same.  But now that I've looked into it, I believe it is.

Answer (score 4):

Edited thanks to Yihui's comment:

```
if( knitr:::is_latex_output() ) {
    xlatex ...
} else {
    DT...
}
```

Comment: You can use `knitr:::is_latex_output()`.

Comment: [Since knitr 1.18](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/NEWS.md#changes-in-knitr-version-118), you can use `knitr::is_latex_output()`, with two colons instead of three.