# RMarkdown: bookdown with plotly

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, plotly, bookdown

I'm using the `bookdown` package with RMarkdown to generate web-based book similar to [this](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/), likewise with the option to download a pdf-version of the book.

I've included `plotly` graphs in my "book" which work nicely in the html-version of the book. Being interactive, the button "build book" throws an error when including pdf output in the YAML-header.

Based on [this description](https://plot.ly/r/static-image-export/) I've found a workaround with a regular RMarkdown File to create pdfs with `plotly` graphs outputs. A minimal solution (outside bookdown) looks like this:

````
---
title: "test"
output:
  pdf_document: default
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(plotly)

Sys.setenv("plotly_username" = "username")
Sys.setenv("plotly_api_key" = "API")
```


```{r cars}
library(plotly)
p <- plot_ly(x = c(1,2,3,4), y = c(2,4,1,3), type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines')
plotly_IMAGE(p, format = "png", out_file = "output.png")

```
![Caption for the picture.](output.png)
````

Is there a way to include this solution within bookdown, so that the graphs are automagically *interactive* in the html output and static (png) in the pdf output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this blogpost](https://www.r-bloggers.com/rmarkdown-alter-action-depending-on-document/) I was able to come up with a solution. Note, this only works

- with the "knitr" button (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35149103/4139249) for a workaround)
- with an internet connection (1) and Plotly Account (2)

(1) See [this link](https://plot.ly/r/static-image-export/) to export static images locally (which I didn't get to work since I failed installing `PhantomJS`)

(2) Plotly has a user Quota of currently 100 plots / grids per user per day

````
---
title: "test"
output:
  html_document: default
  pdf_document: default
  word_document: default
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(plotly)
library(pander)
Sys.setenv("plotly_username" = "YOUR PLOTLY USERNAME")
Sys.setenv("plotly_api_key" = "API KEY")

output <- knitr::opts_knit$get("rmarkdown.pandoc.to") # html / latex / docx

```


```{r, results="asis"}

print(output)

p <- plot_ly(x = c(1,2,3,4), y = c(2,4,1,3), type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines')

filename <- "output.png"

if(output %in% c("latex","docx")){
  plotly_IMAGE(p, format = "png", out_file = filename)
  pandoc.image(filename)
} else if(output == "html"){
  p
} else(print("No format defined for this output filetype"))


```
````

Comment: With html as the output format don't you want to output the full `plotly` object so that the user can interact with it?

Comment: The issue I had was with generating the _pdf_ Version of the book