# R Markdown Different Echo Options for Different Output Types

Tags: r, r-markdown

In R Markdown, is there a way to change the `echo` option for different output types?

In the example below, I'd like to show my code on the `html_document` output (`echo = TRUE`), but would like to hide the code on the `word_document` output (`echo = FALSE`).

Currently, I have the global option to define `knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)` in my first code chunk, which seems to be required for the `html_document` `code_folding` option in the YAML header, but this also shows the code in the `word_document` output.  If I remove this global option, I see the same outcome.  Is there a way to define the echo option in the YAML header, under each of the output types (`word_document` vs. `html_document`)?

Thanks for your help with this.

````
---
title: "test2"
author: "Carina"
date: "February 13, 2020"
output:
  word_document: default
  html_document: 
    code_folding: show

---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function `is_html_output()` to check whether you output is html or not and use that in your first chunk:

````
---
title: "test2"
author: "Carina"
date: "February 13, 2020"
output:
  word_document: default
  html_document: 
    code_folding: show

---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = knitr::is_html_output())
```
````

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to [Gilean0709's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60211349/3817004), we can use the string which is returned by the call to `knitr::opts_knit$get("rmarkdown.pandoc.to")`. This approach is taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35149103/3817004).

````
---
title: "test2"
author: "Carina"
date: "February 13, 2020"
output:
  html_document:
    code_folding: show
  pdf_document: default
  word_document: default
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = knitr::opts_knit$get("rmarkdown.pandoc.to") == "html")
```
````